How to create a rails staging environment?
I have a rails app running in production hosted, now I need a staging environment to run tests. It would be exactly the same as what I have in production, but only changing the database so that one doesn't affect the other.
What is the easiest and least configuration way to do this? If possible, a step-by-step guide, because I'm a frontend developer but I have to solve this problem.
